# pip hangs after installing package

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip

I'm using Python 3 on windows I'm trying to install a package from within a script.

The purpose is that I don't want to explain to the person I'm sending the script how to install the packages he needs, so I'm hoping to do it on the fly from within the script.

Here's my code:

```
import pip

pip.main(["install", 'pyetrade'])

import pyetrade
```

Everything installs correctly with pip.main, however it doesn't move on to "import pyetrade" or the rest of the code. It just hangs there.

Any ideas how to get around this? This also seems to happen when I use the command propt -- it seems to just hang after installation.

Comment: `pip install pyetrade` worked when I tried it on Windows with Python 3.6.2 and a virtual environment. Have you tried using [--log](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#log) for more details? A "last resort" option would be to start something like [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) then run pip. Process Monitor will report every file operation that pip does, which may give a clue as to where and why it's hanging.

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4588. It links to this other issue which is still open: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3532